# d3d Convert 1 descriptor table (2 cbvs) to 2 descriptor table (each one cbv) get screen flicker

Tags: graphics, 3d, directx, direct3d, directx-12

I am learning d3d develpoment recently.

For the triangle example, I add code about model, view matrix setting.
Here I set model, view seperate.

There are 3 methods to do this.

- root constants
- root constant buffer
- cbv in descriptor table

There are no problem except using descriptor table for me.

For descriptor table, there are 3 ways to do. I want to practice them all to learn well-undertsanding of d3d coding.

1. put `2` float4x4 in one constant buffer as 1 descriptor table.
2. put `1` float4x4 in each constant buffer, then as `2` descriptor tables with each has `1` descriptor range.
3. put `1` float4x4 in each constant buffer, then as `1` descriptor table with `2` descriptor ranges.

I have tried the method 1 & 3, but when i try method **2**, I get screen flicker.

Here is my code of method 2 & 3 to comprare. Please help me to find the root casue.

### create root signature

```
#ifdef TABLE_SEPERATE
    /* 2 descriptor table, 2 cbvs*/
    CD3DX12_ROOT_PARAMETER slotRootParameter[2];
    CD3DX12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE dscRange[2];
    dscRange[0].Init(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_CBV, 1, 0);
    dscRange[1].Init(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_CBV, 1, 1);
    slotRootParameter[0].InitAsDescriptorTable(1, &dscRange[0]);
    slotRootParameter[1].InitAsDescriptorTable(1, &dscRange[1]);

    CD3DX12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_DESC rootSignatureDesc;
    rootSignatureDesc.Init(2, slotRootParameter, 0, nullptr, D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_ALLOW_INPUT_ASSEMBLER_INPUT_LAYOUT);
#else
    /* 1 descriptor table, 2 cbvs*/
    CD3DX12_ROOT_PARAMETER slotRootParameter[1];
    CD3DX12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE dscRange[2];
    dscRange[0].Init(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_CBV, 1, 0);
    dscRange[1].Init(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_RANGE_TYPE_CBV, 1, 1);
    slotRootParameter[0].InitAsDescriptorTable(2, &dscRange[0]);

    CD3DX12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_DESC rootSignatureDesc;
    rootSignatureDesc.Init(1, slotRootParameter, 0, nullptr, D3D12_ROOT_SIGNATURE_FLAG_ALLOW_INPUT_ASSEMBLER_INPUT_LAYOUT);
#endif

    ComPtr<ID3DBlob> signature;
    ComPtr<ID3DBlob> error;
    ThrowIfFailed(D3D12SerializeRootSignature(&rootSignatureDesc, D3D_ROOT_SIGNATURE_VERSION_1, &signature, &error));
    ThrowIfFailed(m_d3d12Device->CreateRootSignature(0, signature->GetBufferPointer(), signature->GetBufferSize(), IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_rootSignature)));
```

### create descriptor heaps & constant view

```
    ModelCB model;
    ViewCB view;
    DirectX::XMStoreFloat4x4(&model.model, XMMatrixTranspose(XMMatrixScaling(0.1, 0.1, 1.0)));
    DirectX::XMStoreFloat4x4(&view.view, XMMatrixTranspose(XMMatrixScaling(0.5, 0.5, 1.0))); // For debugging, so do scaling first. easy to see effect.

    m_pModelBuffer = new CUploadBufferResource<ModelCB>(m_d3d12Device.Get(), 1, true);
    m_pViewBuffer = new CUploadBufferResource<ViewCB>(m_d3d12Device.Get(), 1, true);

    m_pViewBuffer->CopyData(0, view);
    m_pModelBuffer->CopyData(0, model);

    D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_DESC cbvHeapDesc;
    cbvHeapDesc.Type = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_CBV_SRV_UAV;
    cbvHeapDesc.Flags = D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_FLAG_SHADER_VISIBLE;
    cbvHeapDesc.NumDescriptors = 2;
    cbvHeapDesc.NodeMask = 0;

    ThrowIfFailed(m_d3d12Device->CreateDescriptorHeap(&cbvHeapDesc, IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_cbvHeap)));

    m_ModelBufferView.BufferLocation = m_pModelBuffer->Resouce()->GetGPUVirtualAddress();
    m_ModelBufferView.SizeInBytes = m_pModelBuffer->GetElementByteSize();
    
    m_ViewBufferView.BufferLocation = m_pViewBuffer->Resouce()->GetGPUVirtualAddress();
    m_ViewBufferView.SizeInBytes = m_pViewBuffer->GetElementByteSize();

    UINT cbv_srv_uavDescriptorSize = m_d3d12Device->GetDescriptorHandleIncrementSize(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_CBV_SRV_UAV);
    auto handle = CD3DX12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE(m_cbvHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart());
    handle.Offset(0, cbv_srv_uavDescriptorSize);
    m_d3d12Device->CreateConstantBufferView(&m_ModelBufferView, handle);

    cbv_srv_uavDescriptorSize = m_d3d12Device->GetDescriptorHandleIncrementSize(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_CBV_SRV_UAV);
    handle = CD3DX12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE(m_cbvHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart());
    handle.Offset(1, cbv_srv_uavDescriptorSize);
    m_d3d12Device->CreateConstantBufferView(&m_ViewBufferView, handle);
```

### shader hlsl

```
cbuffer V : register( b1 )
{
    float4x4 view;
};

cbuffer M : register(b0)
{
    float4x4 model;
};

struct PSInput
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};

PSInput VSMain(float4 position : POSITION, float4 color : COLOR)
{
    PSInput result;
    result.position = mul(mul(position, model), view);
    result.color = color;

    return result;
}

float4 PSMain(PSInput input) : SV_TARGET
{
    return input.color;
}
```

### code in OnRender

##### 1 descriptor table, 2 cbvs [Work]

```
    ID3D12DescriptorHeap* descHeaps[] = { m_cbvHeap.Get() };

    m_commandList->SetDescriptorHeaps(_countof(descHeaps), descHeaps);
    m_commandList->SetPipelineState(m_pipelineState.Get());
    m_commandList->SetGraphicsRootSignature(m_rootSignature.Get());

    UINT cbv_srv_uavDescriptorSize = m_d3d12Device->GetDescriptorHandleIncrementSize(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_CBV_SRV_UAV);

    auto handle = CD3DX12_GPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE(m_cbvHeap->GetGPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart());
    handle.Offset(0, cbv_srv_uavDescriptorSize);
    m_commandList->SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable(0, handle);
```

##### 2 descriptor table. 2 cbvs [NOT WORK]

```
    ID3D12DescriptorHeap* descHeaps[] = { m_cbvHeap.Get() };

    m_commandList->SetDescriptorHeaps(_countof(descHeaps), descHeaps);
    m_commandList->SetPipelineState(m_pipelineState.Get());
    m_commandList->SetGraphicsRootSignature(m_rootSignature.Get());

    UINT cbv_srv_uavDescriptorSize = m_d3d12Device->GetDescriptorHandleIncrementSize(D3D12_DESCRIPTOR_HEAP_TYPE_CBV_SRV_UAV);

    auto handle = CD3DX12_GPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE(m_cbvHeap->GetGPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart());
    handle.Offset(0, cbv_srv_uavDescriptorSize);
    m_commandList->SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable(0, handle);

    handle = CD3DX12_GPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE(m_cbvHeap->GetGPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart());
    handle.Offset(1, cbv_srv_uavDescriptorSize);
    m_commandList->SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable(1, handle);
```